# PHP - replace subquery with join?

Tags: php, join, subquery

Ok, so right now i have a query inside of the while loop from another query...but there's got to be a more efficient way of doing what i'm trying to do.  Can i accomplish the below script via one query? And would that be more efficient? (i'm assuming it would be)  Here's what i have now (not the real code, but a good example):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Bugs LIMIT 5");
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sth->execute();
while($row = $sth->fetch()){
    $bugId = $row->id;
    echo 'Bug Name: ' . $row->name;
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'Affected Web Browsers: ';
    $sth2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM AffectedBrowsers WHERE BugId = '$bugId'");
    $sth2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth2->execute();
    $i = 1;
    while($row2 = $sth2->fetch()){
        if($i = 1){
            echo $row2->browser;
        }else{
            echo ', ' . $row2->browser;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

My tables are as follows:
1) "Bugs" - this table has one row for each bug listed.
2) "AFfectedBrowsers" - this table houses all of the affected browsers for a particular bug.  This table has a relationship with the "Bugs" table via the bugId column in the "AffectedBrowsers" table.

Note: I do realize that incrementing the $i could be done in a for loop instead of an if/else.

**UPDATED: I need just one row per bug and i'm guessing add a column in the result set that has all of the affected browsers for that bug listed.**

Comment: Is the `LIMIT 5` necessary? Or, would it be okay to limit the number of total "affected browsers", regardless of the number of "bugs"?

Comment: The limit 5 is because i only wanted to show 5 bugs on the particular page that this is being implemented on.  but i can't limit the total affected browsers because i need to now every browser that a bug affects.

Comment: See the answer by David Hirst. That `LIMIT 5` is limiting the total result, not the bugs. Instead, if you need to limit the bugs, this complicates things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Bugs
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT BugId, GROUP_CONCAT(Browser) Browsers FROM AffectedBrowsers GROUP BY BugId) Aff
ON Bugs.Id = Aff.BugId
```

Comment: This gives me what i need.  I suppose the only way to do this is through sub queries rather than joins?

Comment: Yes, a join always produces at least one row for each pair of matching rows in the two tables. If you only want one row for each bug, you need to reduce the table you join with to one matching row. Also, if you want to see bugs with no affected browsers (as your PHP could), you should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM Bugs
INNER JOIN AffectedBrowsers ON Bugs.Id = AffectedBrowsers.BugId
LIMIT 5
```

Is that what your looking for?

Comment: hehe yes though I am making the assumption that the Bugs primary key is called Id ;)

Comment: sure it is the *relevant* key: `$bugId = $row->id;`

Comment: This gets me close.  Although, when running this query, if there are multiple browsers (i.e., Firefox, Chrome, and Safari) affected by one bug then i get three rows back from the query instead of one row with a column listing all of the affected browsers.  Maybe i mis-worded my question on that part.  I need just one row per bug and i'm guessing add a column in the result set that has all of the affected browsers for that bug listed.

Comment: `INNER JOIN AffectedBrowsers ON Bugs.Id = AffectedBrowsers.BugId` works...it's just for example anyways.

Comment: just check the `Bugs` ID while processing the result set. Only start a new row when that ID changes and just add it to the affected browsers column otherwise. Add a  `ORDER BY Bugs.ID` in that case to have the bugs remain somewhat grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Bugs 
LEFT JOIN AffectedBrowsers 
ON Bugs.BugId = AffectedBrowsers.BugId 
LIMIT 5
```

If you want to list bugs, even if there are no affected browsers. By the way, you should get into the habit of listing out what columns you wan't to retrieve data from.

Comment: yea i know, it will be in my prod code...this was just example code.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good. However, if you need to limit the number of bugs and don't care about the number of affected browsers, use this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM AffectedBrowsers
  WHERE BugID IN ( SELECT id FROM Bugs LIMIT 5 )
```

Note that this is a real subquery. But, unlike your code, it is contained in one single statement and should still be faster.

Comment: Yea, thought about this but i always get weary of these sub queries.

Comment: That's why I asked about the `LIMIT`. I see no other solution if you need to limit the bugs. OTOH, with a decent database this should not be slow even with a large database. It's certainly better than starting six queries for the same task.